# Navbar alinear boton derecha y centrarlo bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

tengo este codigo en mi barra de navegacion.
El boton me gustaria ponerlo a la derecha(solo me deja mover los dos) y alineado con los demas items, nose como hacerlo.

Ademas tampoco me funciona el mailto.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="nav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="inicio.php">Logo</a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                             Contacto
                            </a> 
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<!-- NO FUNCIONA MAILTO -->
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="mailto:xxx@gmail.es?Subject=Trabajo%20desde%20web">xxx@gmail.es</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Tel: xx</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Tel: xx</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="container">
                                <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Trabajos</button>
                                <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
                                        <div class="popup" id="popup">
                                            <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con estos cambios.

1. Donde pones esto:

```
<li class="dropdown">
```

pon esto:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

para que te funcione el dropdown en el nav, sino ni se inmuta cuando intentas expandirlo por lo que parece.

2. Donde pones esto:

```
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="container">
    <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Trabajos</button>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
      <div class="popup" id="popup">
        <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</li>
```

pon esto:

```
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Trabajos</button>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
      <div class="popup" id="popup">
        <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

porque así cerramos la primera lista, dejándola a la izquierda, y creamos una nueva con estas clases: `navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto` para que se alinee con la otra y además, gracias a la clase `ms-auto` se desplace al final del **nav**.

También he quitado el div del container porque genera margenes y paddings adicionales que no queremos.

Dejo un snippet de muestra con todo (sólo funciona a pantalla completa):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="inicio.php">Logo</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Contacto
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <!-- NO FUNCIONA MAILTO -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="mailto:xxx@gmail.es?Subject=Trabajo%20desde%20web">xxx@gmail.es</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Tel: xx</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Tel: xx</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Trabajos</button>
            <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
              <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Ya nos diras si te sirve

Comment: Buenas me ha funcionado perfectamente, pero tengo mas dudas ya que estoy empezando, adjunto aqui enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536160/formatos-css-y-mailto

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro. Te informo que las respuestas que te son válidas debes aceptarlas para que las preguntas no queden eternamente pendientes y puedan ayudar a otros que caigan por aqui. Pulsa [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo. Tambien te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para aprender bien el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.